# Additional info in JSON for jQuery dataTable plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins, datatable

jQuery dataTable plugin expects the data (aaData) in a format where aaData is an array of array.Like below

> {    "aaData":[
>         [
>            "1",
>            "2, 3",
>            "4",
>            "5"
>         ]    ] }

Now if I want to send some additional information in my json to make some disicisions like to make the contents of second column a hyperlink or nor.How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try add your own key into JSON?

```
{ "aaData":[ [ "1", "2, 3", "4", "5" ] ], "mydata":{"keyN":1, "keyM": [1,2,3,4] } }
```